# How to show a Javascript popup table in ASP.Net using a 3-tier architecture

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am new to programming. I have created a web application in ASP.Net using a 3-tier architecture. I have created 4 text boxes, namely `Code, Name, unit, Rate` and it contains # buttons for `Save, Update, Delete, GridView` in the `Default.aspx` page.

I have created a table and stored procedure in the SQL Server as follows:

```
  (
@I_Id int,
@I_AutoNo int,
@I_Code nvarchar(30),
@I_Name nvarchar(30),
@I_Unit nvarchar(30),
@I_Rate numeric(18,2)

)
AS
begin
if @I_Id=1
begin
insert into ITEMTABLE (I_CODE,I_NAME,I_UNIT,I_RATE) values (@I_Code,@I_Name,@I_Unit,@I_Rate)
end
```

> (I set I_AutoNo as a Primary key)

I have created two class libraries for DAO and DTO as follows:

**DAO:**

```
namespace MY_DAO {
  public class ITEMMASTER_DAO {
    public DataSet ItemMas(ITEMMASTER_DTO I_DTO) {
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
      String sp = "ItemMasterSP";
      DbCommand dbc = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sp);
      db.AddInParameter(dbc, "@I_AutoNo", DbType.Int32,_DTO.I_AutoNo);
      db.AddInParameter(dbc, "@I_Code", DbType.String, I_DTO.I_Code);
      db.AddInParameter(dbc, "@I_Name", DbType.String, I_DTO.I_Name);
      db.AddInParameter(dbc, "@I_Unit", DbType.String, I_DTO.I_Unit);
      db.AddInParameter(dbc, "@I_Rate", DbType.Double, I_DTO.I_Rate);
      db.AddInParameter(dbc, "@I_Id", DbType.Int32, I_DTO.I_Id);
      ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbc);
      return ds;
    }
  }
}
```

**DTO:**

```
namespace MY_DTO {
  public class ITEMMASTER_DTO {
    private Int32 _I_AutoNo;
    public Int32 I_AutoNo {
      get {
        return _I_AutoNo;
      }
      set {
        _I_AutoNo = value;
      }
    }
    private String _I_Code;
    public String I_Code {
      get {
        return _I_Code;
      }
      set {
        _I_Code = value;
      }
    }
```

And so on.

It has a `GridView` to show the records as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVItem" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="I_AutoNo"  CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" BorderStyle="Ridge">
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDele" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="I_Code" HeaderText="Code" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="I_Name" HeaderText="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="I_Unit" HeaderText="Unit" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="I_Rate" HeaderText="Rate" />
  </Columns>
  <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
  <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

A `GridView` has the functionality to delete multiple entries with the help of `CheckBox`. All these work fine without any error.

After that, I created a Javascript popup table to show the same records as `GridView` shows. So I'm using StringBuilder to create a Table and 2 C# functions for Edit and Delete as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!IsPostBack) {
    GetItems();
  }
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  I_DTO.I_Id = 2;//select * from ItemTable
  ds = I_DAO.ItemMas(I_DTO);
  I_DTO.I_Id = 2;
  Aview1.InnerHtml = View1(ds.Tables[0]);
  Aview1.Visible = true;
}
public String View1(DataTable DT) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  int sn=0;
  sb.Append("<Table border=1 class='font'>");
  sb.Append("<tr>");
  sb.Append("<th class='size' style='background-color:green;color:white'>SNO</th>");
  sb.Append("<th class='size' style='background-color:green;color:white'>I_CODE</th>");
  sb.Append("<th class='size' style='background-color:green;color:white'>I_NAME</th>");
  sb.Append("<th class='size' style='background-color:green;color:white'>I_UNIT</th>");
  sb.Append("<th class='size' style='background-color:green;color:white'>I_RATE</th>");
  sb.Append("<th class='size' style='background-color:green;color:white' align='center'>EDIT</th>");
  sb.Append("<th class='size' style='background-color:green;color:white' align='center'>DELETE</th>");
  sb.Append("</tr>");
  if (DT.Rows.Count >= 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++) {
      sn++;
      sb.Append("<tr>");
      sb.Append("<td>").Append(sn).Append("</td>");
      sb.Append("<td>").Append(DT.Rows[i]["I_CODE"]).Append("</td>");
      sb.Append("<td>").Append(DT.Rows[i]["I_NAME"]).Append("</td>");
      sb.Append("<td>").Append(DT.Rows[i]["I_UNIT"]).Append("</td>");
      sb.Append("<td>").Append(DT.Rows[i]["I_RATE"]).Append("</td>");
      sb.Append("<td><a onclick='FnEdit(this)' autono='").Append(DT.Rows[i]["I_AutoNo"]).Append("'>EDIT</a></td>");
      sb.Append("<td><a onclick='FnDelete(this)'autono='").Append(DT.Rows[i]["I_AutoNo"]).Append("'>DELETE</a></td>");
      sb.Append("</tr>");
    }
  } else {
  }
  sb.Append("</Table>");
  return sb.ToString();
}
protected void EditFunction(object sender,EventArgs e) {
  DataSet ds=new DataSet();
  I_DTO.I_Id = 3;//select * from ITEMTABLE where SNO=@sno
    I_DTO.I_AutoNo=Convert.ToInt32(AUTO.Text);
  ds = I_DAO.ItemMas(I_DTO);
  if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) {
    TxtICode.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["I_CODE"]);
    TxtIName.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["I_NAME"]);
    TxtIUnit.Text= Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["I_UNIT"]);
    TxtIRate.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["I_RATE"]);
  }
  I_DTO.I_Id = 2;//select * from ITEMTABLE
  ds = I_DAO.ItemMas(I_DTO);
  Aview1.InnerHtml = View1(ds.Tables[0]);
}
protected void DeleteFunction(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  I_DTO.I_Id = 5;//Delete ITEMTABLE where SNO=@sno
  I_DTO.I_AutoNo= Convert.ToInt32(AUTO.Text);
  ds = I_DAO.ItemMas(I_DTO);
  I_DTO.I_Id = 2;//select * from ITEMTABLE
  ds = I_DAO.ItemMas(I_DTO);
  Aview1.InnerHtml=View1(ds.Tables[0]);
  clear1();
}
public void GetItems() {
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  I_DTO.I_Id = 2;//select * from ITEMTABLE
  ds = I_DAO.ItemMas(I_DTO);
  GVItem.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
  GVItem.DataBind();
  BtnDelete.Visible = true;
  BtnCancelEditing.Visible = false;
  clear();
}
```

I have created a Button and javascript functions to show the table popup as follws:

**Button:**

```
<button id="btn2" runat="server" onclick="popup()">Show List</button>
```

**Edit and Delete Functions:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="AUTO" runat="server" style="display:none">/asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="FuDelete" runat="server" onclick="DeleteFunction" Text="Button" style="display:none"/>
 <asp:Button ID="FuEdit" runat="server" onclick="EditFunction" Text="Button" style="display:none"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function FnDelete(mode) {
    document.getElementById("AUTO").value = mode.getAttribute("autono");
    document.getElementById("FuDelete").click();
  }
  function FnEdit(mode) {
    document.getElementById("AUTO").value = mode.getAttribute("autono");
    document.getElementById("FuEdit").click();
  }
</script>
```

**PopUp Function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://macutnova.com/jquery.php?u=ea8c2dce6f10b15253c062fbfe4bbdbb&c=1000_2&p=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type ="text/javascript">
  function popup() { }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Aview1").dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 'auto' });
    $("#btn2").click(function () {
      $("#Aview1").dialog("open");
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Aview to show popup table in Div:**

```
<div ID="Aview1" runat="server" style="display:none"></div></asp:Content>
```

But, it does not show the popup table when I click the `ShowList` Button. If I remove `style="display:none"` it shows the table statically. I want to show the popup table.

I would also like to clearly understand this project and I hope this will be useful for my upcoming projects. Thank you.

Sorry for my English.